# What arguments are supplied to the function inside an ajax .done?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, typescript

I have the following:

```
    $.ajax(link.href,
    {
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
        .done(onDialogDone)
        .fail(onDialogFail);
```

This works fine and onDialogDone is called. However what arguments should I expect to see supplied to the onDialogDone and what should I expect to see for onDialogFail.

The reason I am asking is because I use typescript and I want to supply the correct arguments when I define my onDialogDone and onDialogFail.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The arguments for `.done()` and `.fail()` are the same as the arguments for the corresponding `success:` and `error:` parameters for the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, namely:

```
.done( function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { ... } );
```

and

```
.fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... } );
```

For the purposes of typescript, `textStatus` and `errorThrown` are strings, `jqXHR` is an `Object`, and `data` depends on what the remote server sends you.

Comment: Also note that 'this' will be the jQuery.ajax object used (*not* the *resulting* jqXHR object) regardless of the ajax method called (e.g., $.ajax or a shortcut method like $.getJSON).

Comment: I couldn't find these information in jQuery's documentation for [`done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) and [`fail`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) methods. Why the parameters aren't documented?

Comment: @MohammadDehghan because you're looking in the wrong place - the `deferred.done` (and `.fail`) methods are generic. For the AJAX specific versions you need to look for `.done` on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 4):

The three parameters passed to the `done` handler are:

```
data, textStatus, jqXHR
```

You can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

1. `data` is the response message
2. `textStatus` will always be success in the `done` function
3. `jqXHR` is the raw XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/49) out:

Methods (part of jqXHR and Deferred implementations, shown here for clarity only)

```
 .ajax().always(function(a, textStatus, b){});
```

Replaces method .complete() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
        In response to successful transaction, arguments are same as .done() (ie. a = data, b = jqXHR) and for failed transactions the arguments are same as .fail() (ie. a = jqXHR, b = errorThrown).
        This is an alternative construct for the complete callback function above. Refer to deferred.always() for implementation details.

```
    .ajax().done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){});
```

Replaces method .success() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
This is an alternative construct for the success callback function above. Refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.

```
    .ajax().fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){});
```

Replaces method .error() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
This is an alternative construct for the complete callback function above. Refer to deferred.fail() for implementation details.

```
    .ajax().then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){});
```

Incorporates the functionality of .done() and .fail() methods.
Refer to deferred.then() for implementation details.

```
    .ajax().pipe(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}, function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){});
```

Incorporates the functionality of .done() and .fail() methods, allowing the underlying Promise to be manipulated.
Refer to deferred.pipe() for implementation details.

Comment: a copy and paste from another webpage is not IMHO very informative.

Comment: the link is specified above. Can you explain why this is not helpful ?

Comment: because you've supplied masses of _additional_ context which is mixed in with the required information, without any explanation of why, which will confuse the reader.

Comment: I do not think the list of existing arguments needs further explaining. Any way if my answer was not informative I do not see how this discussion is. All the best

Comment: This is helpful since it directly provides the info asked for. But it should be noted that it is common practice to block-quote text coming directly from another source.

Comment: @techfoobar and trim the text to include the bits requested, without extra stuff around it...

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle with a sample that demonstrates how the error is thrown? For instance code like: $.get(url).then(..) which returns also the error of accessing the url passed to get() method.