# Outputting Response Status Code From AJAX Response To console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to output the status codes from my parse.com server Rest API response via console.log() in my web app using Javascript.

My AJAX response is set as follows:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                            console.log("Return Code: " + response.status);
                        })
                        .fail(function(response) {
                            console.log("Return Code: " + response.status);
                        });
```

Heres a screenshot of the network responses from Chrome when I'm attempting to create a new user & get a successful response:

[image: 201 Created]

The console.log doesn't output "201" as I'd expect.

However, once the user is created & I try again & see the following response:

[image: 400 Bad Response]

... I see "Response Code: 400" output into the console.  I'm confused as to why this is working on the 400 & not the 201 response.

I've also tried the following, but it still reads out "undefined":

```
            $.ajax(settings).done(function(response, xhr) {
                    console.log("Return Code: " + xhr.status);
```

Comment: This is what was returned from the server, show us your server side code and not just your JS ajax call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141028/what-arguments-are-supplied-to-the-function-inside-an-ajax-done
There are 3 arguments in the `Success` and `Fail` functions

Comment: @bobjoe Thanks for the link.  So, I've now got it working with  `.done(function(response, jqXHR, data) {
                            console.log("Return Code: " + data.status);` - interestingly, I need to have jqXHR otherwise it doesn't work?

Comment: If you leave out jqXHR, what you are doing is really calling the success function like this
`.done(function(response, data)` but `data` will really be `jqXHR` and the `data` object will be neglected.

Comment: OK.  I sort of get you.  So, the order presumably matters also?

Comment: Similarly, take a look at a similar post that I've written recently here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875054/output-rest-api-status-displayed-in-postman-to-ajax