# Output REST API Status Displayed In Postman To AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, postman

In Postman, I can successfully communicate with my REST API.  I can put my API server in various artificial states to represent 2xx, 4xx & 5xx errors which I can successfully view in Postman as follows:

[image: 403]

[image: 404]

[image: 505]

[image: 203]

Postman is able to collect this info, regardless of whether or not the API server is running & it appears to be a generic status response, vs. a response that the API app produces.

My question is, how do I output this into a console.log() in my Javascript App?

In my instance, I want to output the status inside an AJAX function at the backend of a form submit:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function(response, jqXHR, data) {
        console.log("Return Code: " + data.status);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Return Code: " + ??? );
    });
});
```

My data.status works fine when I get a success, but presumably there is a variable that I can tap into that is the generic status message?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the returned status code from the `status` property of the `jqXHR` object:

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Return Code: " + jqXHR.status);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mzmd5nx8/)

Comment: This works fine when the API server is on & operational.  It produces as 400 response when the user already exists for example.  But if I stop the API App (which is hosted on Azure) I get a 403 response.  If I restart the server, I temporarily get a 503 response.  These both output to the console with a return code of 0, not 403 or 503.